# How to configure npm per project for my teammates to have the same config?

Tags: node.js, npm

Recently, I ran accross a `npm install` issue, where I had to do either: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` either `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`.

I'm not really sure why, but anyway, since it's a team project, that we have some devops scripts, I would like to know if there is a way to basically have a file with information on how npm should be configured for the team.

Something in the package.json or an .something to make sure everybody using this repository have a the `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a [per-project configuration file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc#per-project-config-file), aka a `.npmrc` file that sits alongside `package.json` and is committed into source control.

```properties
# .npmrc
legacy-peer-deps=true
```